# How to perform interpolation on a 2D array in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, interpolation

How can I make a function of 2 variables and given a 2D array, it would return an interpolated value?

I have `N x M` array `A`. I need to interpolate it and somehow obtain the function of that surface so I could pick values on not-integer arguments. 
(I need to use that interpolation as a function of 2 variables)

For example:

```
A[N,M] //my array
// here is the method I'm looking for. Returns function interpolatedA
interpolatedA(3.14,344.1) //That function returns interpolated value
```

Comment: search help for cubic splines, or the `spline()` command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For data on a regular grid, use [interp2](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp2.html). If your data is scattered, use [griddata](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/griddata.html). You can create an [anonymous function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) as a simplified wrapper around those calls.

```
M = 10;
N = 5;
A = rand(M,N);
interpolatedA = @(y,x) interp2(1:N,1:M,A,x,y);
%interpolatedA = @(y,x) griddata(1:N,1:M,A,x,y); % alternative
interpolatedA(3.3,8.2)

ans =
      0.53955
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think that's not what I need. 
As far as I see, using those functions, I can only create another array with surface values.
But I need to use interpolation of an array as a function. (I've edited the question)

Comment: @Max You can use these functions to interpolate any number of points. You can get one value at the specific [x,y] that you want.

Comment: Thanks! That was easy one, I should've guessed myself.
I'm kinda newbie yet, sorry :)

Comment: Just a note: x and y values correspond to `column` and `row` not the other way around. So `interpolated(3.3,8.2)` is returning a value in the region of `A(8,3)`

Comment: @geometrikal Thanks! I updated the anonymous function so inputs are ordered (y,x) just like array indexing.

Answer (score 6):

Here is an example using [`scatteredInterpolant`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatteredinterpolantclass.html):

```
%# get some 2D matrix, and plot as surface
A = peaks(15);
subplot(121), surf(A)

%# create interpolant
[X,Y] = meshgrid(1:size(A,2), 1:size(A,1));
F = scatteredInterpolant(X(:), Y(:), A(:), 'linear');

%# interpolate over a finer grid
[U,V] = meshgrid(linspace(1,size(A,2),50), linspace(1,size(A,1),50));
subplot(122), surf(U,V, F(U,V))
```

[image: pic]

Note that you can evaluate the interpolant object at any point:

```
>> F(3.14,3.41)
ans =
     0.036288
```

the above example uses a vectorized call to interpolate at all points of the grid

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the `interp2` function?

From MatLab documentation:

`ZI = interp2(X,Y,Z,XI,YI)` returns matrix `ZI` containing elements corresponding to the elements of `XI` and `YI` and determined by interpolation within the two-dimensional function specified by matrices `X`, `Y`, and `Z`. `X` and `Y` must be monotonic, and have the same format ("plaid") as if they were produced by `meshgrid`. Matrices `X` and `Y` specify the points at which the data `Z` is given. Out of range values are returned as `NaN`s.

Comment: Thanks, but I think that's not what I need. 
As far as I see, using those functions, I can only create another array with surface values.
But I need to use interpolation of an array as a function. (I've edited the question)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `spline()` command like this:

```
% A contains N rows and 2 columns
pp = spline(A(:,1), A(:,2));
ppval(pp,3.44)

ans =

    0.4454
```